# Registering the app with firebase - "google-services.json" file and "build.cradle" file

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3

I am reading couple of articles on using firebase in an ionic app. I have created a working Ionic / firebase integration app that uses the Ionic Cloud messaging feature to send notifications on app.

To achieve this (besides the app code) and to integrate firebase in the app: I created the firebase project and selected the android icon - this is to "add firebase to android app". Step 1 is the app name, **Step 2** is downloading the "google-services.json". It advises me to place the file in the applications app directory.

Some articles advise placing the "google-services" file in the root app directory. If I do this I get error when running "ionic cordova run android" which says the "google-services.json" file could not be found.

What works for me and same is advised by many other articles I have read is - place the file in "Application/**platform/android/app**" folder. Here "Application" is name of my ionic project folder.

My question:

1. What is the best practice to place this file? Am I doing it correctly?
2. The next step after is - **Step 3** Add Firebase SDK - which advises user to add certain lines of code to the (project-level) /build.gradle file or (app-level) //build.gradle - I do not do this yet everything seems to be working well for me. So is this automatically done when we run the "ionic cordova run android" command?

Comment: are u using a firebase ionic plugin?

Comment: Yes, Ionic Cloud messaging - it is working OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project you did:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7
```

In which the structure of the project was changed, and now all the `src`, `assets` and all files needed to run the application should be inside the directory `app`. Therefore, the `google-service.json` file location is correct.

Regarding adding firebase sdk in the `build.gradle` file, you do not need to do that since if you are using this plugin [FCM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/), it adds the firebase sdk in the `build.gradle`.

You can see that in the [`plugin.xml`](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/blob/master/plugin.xml) of the plugin:

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+" />
```

more info here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework